# Qt Creator не видит классы Qt. No such file or directory

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcreator

Из репозитория установил `qt-5`. QtCreator v 3.0.1. Не видит классы `QMessageBox`, `QTcpSocket` и другие.. Пишет `No such file or directory`
И при установке не создался автоматически `kit`, так что `qmake` пришлось выбирать вручную `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake`. Для 5 версии пишет: `Qt version is not properly installed, please run make install`.
Что не так с этим `QtCreator`, есть ли ему альтернативы кроме `QDevelop`?

### UPD

Скачал с официального сайта, теперь `qmake` 5 версии ошибку не выдает. Но классы по прежнему не видит

---

Решение: для каждого класса нужно дописывать в `.pro` файл свои ссылки. Для `QDialog` надо написать QT += widget, для `QTcpSocket` `QT += network`

Comment: А зачем ставить из репозитория? у одногруппника Ubuntu, он качал установщик с оф сайта, и у него всё классно.

Comment: @ВячеславСавченко сейчас попробую скачать с оф сайта

Comment: @ВячеславСавченко не работает, точнее то же самое

Comment: Для [`QTcpSocket`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpsocket.html) убедитесь, что в `.pro` файле есть запись `QT += network`, а в исходнике подключен соответствующий хедер `#include <QTcpSocket>`. С остальными классами аналогично: ищете описание класса и проверяете, что выполняются все необходимые условия.

Comment: Не знаю как на linux, а вот на виндовс под каждый компиль нужен свой qmake, мб я не прав, если так, то просьба поправить.